# IOS: How to get placeholder text to return if UITextField empty?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have placeholder text in a `UITextField`. If someone writes the placeholder text disappears which is what I would like. But then if they delete that writing the placeholder text doesn't reappear. I am trying to work out how to make it reappear if after editing the textfield is empty.

My app is in swift.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you using the "Placeholder" attribute in the Attribute inspector?

Comment: it should be automatic if you are using textField.placeholder

Comment: It was using the placeholder attribute. I changed it to setting it programmatically and it worked. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An extension like this should provide what you want. If need be, you can also move the logic to `textFieldShouldReturn`, if that suits your app better:

```
extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

        guard let text = textField.text, !text.isEmpty else {
            textField.placeholder = "Your placeholder text"

            return true
        }

        return true
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()

        return true
    }
}
```